# Почему потоки не прибиваются, а паркуются после get()

Tags: java

```
     Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        Runnable task = () -> {
            System.out.println("Задача начала выполняться в потоке: " + 
                      Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Это задача, выполняемая в ином потоке, отличном от потока main: " + 
                      Thread.currentThread().getName());
        };

List<CompletableFuture<Void>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(runAsync(task, executor));
        }
        list.forEach(x -> {
                    try {
                        x.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что они должны прибиваться? Вся суть пулов в переиспользовании потоков.

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.